# WPF: CustomControls vs UserControls

Tags: wpf, user-controls, custom-controls

In WPF, what is the differences between CustomControls and UserControls? When should I use each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UserControl (Composition):

- Composes multiple existing controls
  into a reusable "group"
- Consists of a XAML and a code behind
  file
- Cannot be styled/templated
- Derives from UserControl

---

CustomControl (Extending an existing control)

- Extends an existing control with
  additional features
- Consists of a code file and a default
  style in Themes/Generic.xaml
- Can be styled/templated
- The best approach to build a control
  library

---

Source: [The differences between CustomControls and UserControls](http://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomVsUserControl.html)